# Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L, : invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument

Tags: r

When I submit [priceR](https://github.com/stevecondylios/priceR/tree/cae233bbe61f1b14f5397593b1d045d8a784d1d3) to [R-hub](https://builder.r-hub.io/), I see the following [logs](https://builder.r-hub.io/status/original/priceR_0.1.6.tar.gz-c1ce075dcb94af85562b5142836daa9e):

```
### ** Examples
> 
> 
> format_currency("2423562534234", "$")
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument
Calls: format_currency ... sub -> is.factor -> format -> format.default -> prettyNum
Execution halted
* checking for unstated dependencies in ‘tests’ ... OK
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘testthat.R’
 ERROR
Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
Last 13 lines of output:
    7. ├─base::paste0(symbol, .)
    8. ├─base::trimws(.)
    9. │ ├─base:::mysub(...)
   10. │ │ └─base::sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE)
   11. │ │   └─base::is.factor(x)
   12. │ └─base:::mysub(paste0("^", whitespace, "+"), x)
   13. │   └─base::sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE)
   14. │     └─base::is.factor(x)
   15. ├─base::format(...)
   16. └─base::format.default(...)
   17.   └─base::prettyNum(...)
  
  [ FAIL 4 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 30 ]
  Error: Test failures
  Execution halted
```

#### What causes the error?

The logs say `format_currency("2423562534234", "$")` causes the error.

`format_currency()` is [defined as](https://github.com/stevecondylios/priceR/blob/master/R/format.R#L37-L52):

```
library(tidyverse) 

format_currency <- function(amount, symbol, digits) {

  if(missing(digits)) { digits <- 0 }

  symbol_regex <- gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", symbol)

  amount %>%
    gsub(",", "", .) %>%
    as.numeric %>%
    round(., digits) %>%
    format(big.mark = ",", digits = digits, scientific = FALSE, nsmall = digits) %>%
    trimws %>%
    paste0(symbol, .)

}

# Example usage
format_currency("2423562534234", "$")
# "$2,423,562,534,234"
```

#### What I've tried

`?format` says:

> used for prettying (longish) numerical and complex sequences. Passed to `prettyNum`: that help page explains the details.

I tried changing `if(missing(digits)) { digits <- 0 }` to `if(missing(digits)) { digits <- 0L }` but the same error persisted.

Note that the time to try new things is very slow because the package has to be built the submitted to R-hub, which takes around 6-10 minutes to reproduce the build and eventually the error (if someone's running linux, they may be able to reproduce locally for much faster attempts to fix! - unfortunately I presently do not have access to a linux machine).

Any ideas?

#### Further attempts

Thanks to @Onyambu's suggestion to try `digits <- 1` as a default in `format_currency()`. With this default, it looks like [the examples/tests will pass](https://builder.r-hub.io/status/original/priceR_0.1.6.tar.gz-5264327b7725514665d3732bd3cd25ea). But instead of producing `"$2,423,562,534,234"`, it now produces `"$2,423,562,534,234.0"`, which is undesirable. But it does show that changing the digits value to some positive integer alleviates the error.

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘priceR-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> ### Name: format_currency
> ### Title: Make numeric currency values human readable
> ### Aliases: format_currency
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> 
> format_currency("2423562534234", "$")
[1] "$2,423,562,534,234.0"
> # "$2,423,562,534,234"
> 
> format_currency("2423562534234.876", "$", 0)
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument
Calls: format_currency ... sub -> is.factor -> format -> format.default -> prettyNum
Execution halted
```

#### Update: Closing the case (for now)

For future reference, [this](https://builder.r-hub.io/status/original/priceR_0.1.6.tar.gz-770e65a35f309a37582d0b43b2d80224) was the last set of error logs. Note from the relevant excerpt that I can't tell which test failed, just that at least one of them did fail - this makes fixing the problem impractically slow when taking this approach:

```
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘testthat.R’
 ERROR
Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
Last 13 lines of output:
    6. ├─base::paste0(symbol, .)
    7. ├─base::trimws(.)
    8. │ ├─base:::mysub(...)
    9. │ │ └─base::sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE)
   10. │ │   └─base::is.factor(x)
   11. │ └─base:::mysub(paste0("^", whitespace, "+"), x)
   12. │   └─base::sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE)
   13. │     └─base::is.factor(x)
   14. ├─base::format(...)
   15. └─base::format.default(...)
   16.   └─base::prettyNum(...)
  
  [ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 29 ]
  Error: Test failures
  Execution halted
```

The cycle time for making changes and checking is about 15 minutes, too slow to quick diagnosis and fixes. In the interest of efficacy, I'm omitting tests for this family of functions from the package to fit within CRAN requirements.

My plan in future is to investigate how to quickly spin up a cloud (AWS) instance so I can test with a much faster cycle time, hopefully just a few seconds between making a change and testing it on the operating system that produces the issues.

Comment: could you try changing the default of digits to any other positive number eg 1 or 2?

Comment: @Onyambu I'm not sure. I'll try and report back in ~10 min). Note that the function should not have excessive digits if the user doesn't want them. But I can try to see what result it produces when changed to default to 1 digit rather than 0.

Comment: Hi @Onyambu I updated the question with the details of your suggestion. Basically, it looks like `digits` values other than 0 work, it is important that I get the 0 to work so that the function formats correctly

Comment: Could you consider the digits to be NULL as the default

Comment: @Onyambu great idea. I'll try that and update with the outcome

Comment: I too am experiencing this on Ubuntu with Modeltime. My feeling is that someone updated some code in the latest version of R to not allow format() to use digits = 0. I believe this is an issue that needs fixed quickly inside of R.

Comment: @MattDancho that could explain it. I wonder if someone has easy access to the linux builds for testing.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel please feel free to ignore, but figured you may have ideas on this? (see matt's comment above ^)

Comment: @MattDancho I haven't had the chance to investigate thoroughly yet, but I came across this, which may give further explanation: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18098

Comment: @stevec This is great to hear. It looks like r-project is aware. I hope they get it fixed and implemented soon.

Answer (score 10):

This a new ‘feature’ in R 4.1.*.

On the R News page, it says:

> Setting `digits = 0` in `format()`, `print.default()` (and hence typically `print()`) or `options()` is again invalid. Its behaviour was platform-dependent, and it is unclear what “zero significant digits” should mean ([PR#18098](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18098)).

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

They call it a ‘bug fix’, but I think this is an utterly bad design choice. Setting `digits` to 0 makes perfectly sense to me. But unfortunately we have to keep ourselves from using it.